# Angular js partial controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angular js folder structure as below. I am using angular ui router for routing. My question is i have included the link for the HomeController.js in index.html but it seems that angular ui router can't find the controller. Any solution? perhaps a way to directly include the link for the controller instead of controller name?

```html
    app/
        index.html
        app.js
        Home/
            home.html
            HomeController.js
        Contact/
            contact.html
            ContactController.js
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.router'];
        app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) { 
         $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
            $stateProvider
                .state('home', {
                    url: '/',
                    templateUrl: 'Home/home.html',
                    controller: 'homeController'
                })
                .state('contact', {
                    ...
                });
        });

// working if is in same js file, not working if on different js file 
app.controller('homeController', function ($scope) {
 $scope.logoName = 'myLogo';
});
```

```html
<!-- body.html -->
...
<div ui-view>

</div>
...


<!-- home.html -->
<div ng-controller="bsCarouselController">
   {{logoName}}
</div>
```

Comment: please recheck name that you have given in ContactController.js for example myApp.conroller('homeController',function(){});

Comment: i am pretty sure is correct. It work if i throw the controller into app.js but not separate the controller out

Comment: Can you provide fiddle for more understanding because I think there would be a little mistake that is causing error.. Is there any error in console??

Comment: Error was coming because the name inside ng-controller is different form stateProvider 'home-controller' and need not to write ng-controller if you  are providing it through stateProvider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with AngularJS with UI router, I always try to go through this checklist whenever I find myself in trouble.

- Include your `controller.js` file in `index.html` and cross check that your browser console does not log a **404** for a GET request of this file. (Use [Wiredep](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep) to automate this)
- Make sure the name of your `controller` is the same in constructor as well as in your `state` definition.
- If you are using `IIFE`, then make sure you call that in the end.

```
(function() {
    angular
      .module("app")
      .controller("HomeCtrl", HomeCtrl);

    function HomeCtrl() {
    }
  })();
```

- Make sure the `Module` under which your `controller` is declared is injected into your main `bootstrap` module definition and also cross check if all other dependencies are resolved.

Looking at your question, I don't think you can directly include link for the controller in your state definition options object. But you can crosscheck all of the above points and also copy and paste the error in your console. That would help in finding a faster solution.

And looking at your recent comment, I think that it is because of `Module` dependencies problem. Point **#4**.

Make sure you specify the module under which you want to define your controller.

If it is an existing module (**i.e** Previously defined):

```
angular
  .module("existingModule")
  .controller("HomeCtrl", function() {} )
```

If it is a new module

```
angular
  .module("newModule", []) // Make sure you inject this newModule in app.js
  .controller("HomeCtrl", function() {})
```

**Edit:**
  Looking at your update, you have explicitly assigned a controller in your markup using `ng-controller`. Any angular expressions inside this `div` prototypically inherits from `bsCarouselController` , `homeController` and `RootScope`.

Comment: still trying your suggestion. If controller url cannot be included directy. Let say i have 100 controller in 100 js file, then i need to update it to include the 100js file in script src on main index.html?

Comment: You need not. You can do under one module and under one file. But it gets messy. You should ideally have one controller per feature. That's why I recommended using wiredep to automate this task

Comment: great i have found the solution by removing ng-controller